# What is missing to make a successful payment between payer and recipient?

Tags: transactions, balances, payments, state-channels, finality

I tested both `signing payment` and `signature verification` that is implemented by `JavaScript` and `EthereumJS` [here](https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/02/23/writing-a-simple-payment-channel/):

And both of them (signing and verification) properly work, meaning that I am sure the signature is verified successfully in `off-chain` part by `EthereumJS`. I signed the payment as follows:

```
signPayment('0x5A375e7eb3763261BfB74bc53c49B754887b0dc2', 10, function(err, something) {}); 
//signature= 0x0fd0ceca10baada793b3103bcc7ba7523ec8fc79aa070bc8fe9301fc72c0c8424804b3064095a201af464a35483ce55c4aee1fe56aebf0f99bb31b682679b21a1c
```

Then, I deployed the `Solidity` contract as follows:

```
const thisContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi);

    thisContract.deploy({  

            data: bytecode,

            arguments: [ "0x84f0c8fC2F6bc8394EB77BaAAe89cB6e12C048C2", 2592000]

        }).send({

           from: "0x3455D7167A2EE2d660EE85F8e90C6b3B1cCB7163",

           gas: 5000000 ,

           gasPrice: '3000000000',

           value: 5000 

        },

        function(error, transactionHash) {

            console.log(error);

            console.log(transactionHash);

            console.log('function exec');

        }).then(function(newContractInstance) {

        console.log('Contract Instance:' + newContractInstance.options.address);

    });
```

And the result is as follows:

```
> web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount('0x3455D7167A2EE2d660EE85F8e90C6b3B1cCB7163', 'logic')
Promise {
  <pending>,
  domain: 
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { removeListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        newListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        error: [Function: debugDomainError] },
     _eventsCount: 3,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] } }
> 
> const thisContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi);
undefined
> 
> thisContract.deploy({  
... 
...         data: bytecode,
... 
...         arguments: [ "0x84f0c8fC2F6bc8394EB77BaAAe89cB6e12C048C2", 2592000]
... 
...     }).send({
... 
...        from: "0x3455D7167A2EE2d660EE85F8e90C6b3B1cCB7163",
... 
...        gas: 5000000 ,
... 
...        gasPrice: '3000000000',
... 
...        value: 5000 
... 
...     },
... 
...     function(error, transactionHash) {
... 
...         console.log(error);
... 
...         console.log(transactionHash);
... 
...         console.log('function exec');
... 
...     }).then(function(newContractInstance) {
... 
...     console.log('Contract Instance:' + newContractInstance.options.address);
... 
... });
Promise {
  <pending>,
  domain: 
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { removeListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        newListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        error: [Function: debugDomainError] },
     _eventsCount: 3,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] } }
> null
0x31ae8f166914576293258855f248926e60f7d5b75f1bc6514b1cc6375f9e0071
function exec
Contract Instance:0x5A375e7eb3763261BfB74bc53c49B754887b0dc2
```

So, the `payer address` is `0x3455D7167A2EE2d660EE85F8e90C6b3B1cCB7163` and its balance is `19994680471999980000` as follows:

```
> web3.eth.getBalance('0x3455D7167A2EE2d660EE85F8e90C6b3B1cCB7163').then(console.log)
Promise {
  <pending>,
  domain: 
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { removeListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        newListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        error: [Function: debugDomainError] },
     _eventsCount: 3,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] } }
> 19994680471999980000
```

And the `contract address` is `0x5A375e7eb3763261BfB74bc53c49B754887b0dc2`. And when I get contract balance, it is = `5000 wei` as follows :

```
> web3.eth.getBalance('0x5A375e7eb3763261BfB74bc53c49B754887b0dc2').then(console.log)
Promise {
  <pending>,
  domain: 
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { removeListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        newListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        error: [Function: debugDomainError] },
     _eventsCount: 3,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] } }
> 5000
```

Also the `recipient address` is `0x84f0c8fC2F6bc8394EB77BaAAe89cB6e12C048C2` and its balance is `zero` as follows:

```
> web3.eth.getBalance('0x84f0c8fC2F6bc8394EB77BaAAe89cB6e12C048C2').then(console.log)
Promise {
  <pending>,
  domain: 
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { removeListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        newListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        error: [Function: debugDomainError] },
     _eventsCount: 3,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] } }
> 0
```

Till now, everything is OK. Now, I expect when I close the channel by `recipient address` (`0x84f0c8fC2F6bc8394EB77BaAAe89cB6e12C048C2`), its balance changes `from 0 to 10 wei`.

However, when I invoke the function close, apparently it is done as follows:

```
> var contractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, '0x3455D7167A2EE2d660EE85F8e90C6b3B1cCB7163');
undefined

> contractInstance.methods.close(10, "0x0fd0ceca10baada793b3103bcc7ba7523ec8fc79aa070bc8fe9301fc72c0c8424804b3064095a201af464a35483ce55c4aee1fe56aebf0f99bb31b682679b21a1c").send({ from: '0x84f0c8fC2F6bc8394EB77BaAAe89cB6e12C048C2' }, function(error, result) {
... 
...     console.log(error);
... 
...     console.log(result)
... 
... });
Promise {
  <pending>,
  domain: 
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { removeListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        newListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        error: [Function: debugDomainError] },
     _eventsCount: 3,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] },
  _events: undefined,
  emit: [Function: emit],
  on: [Function: on],
  once: [Function: once],
  off: [Function: removeListener],
  listeners: [Function: listeners],
  addListener: [Function: on],
  removeListener: [Function: removeListener],
  removeAllListeners: [Function: removeAllListeners] }
> null
0x233a560fc4553ddb2155e9f7fba9830353530f86d5146efff417739703700525
(node:4688) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Transaction ran out of gas. Please provide more gas:
{
  "blockHash": "0xb170db055aba65c0b3756bac19f4c29684e6d654575295beeba5de77649b064e",
  "blockNumber": 5523048,
  "contractAddress": null,
  "cumulativeGasUsed": 51428,
  "gasUsed": 26392,
  "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "root": null,
  "status": false,
  "transactionHash": "0x233a560fc4553ddb2155e9f7fba9830353530f86d5146efff417739703700525",
  "transactionIndex": 1,
  "events": {}
}
    at /home/s/node_modules/web3-core-method/src/index.js:370:33
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:182:7)
(node:4688) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:4688) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

And here is the transaction information in `Tobalaba Etherscan` :

https://tobalaba.etherscan.com/tx/0x233a560fc4553ddb2155e9f7fba9830353530f86d5146efff417739703700525

However, when I get the `recipient balance`, it is still `zero` :

```
> web3.eth.getBalance('0x84f0c8fC2F6bc8394EB77BaAAe89cB6e12C048C2').then(console.log)
Promise {
  <pending>,
  domain: 
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { removeListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        newListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        error: [Function: debugDomainError] },
     _eventsCount: 3,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] } }
> 0
```

***What is missing to make a "successful" payment between "payer" and "recipient" ?***

Note: As you can see in the output of the transaction, it is written that

> (node:4688) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Transaction ran
>   out of gas. Please provide more gas:

Can it cause this problem ? And if so, how can I increase the `gas` at the time of invoking `contractInstance.methods.close` ?

Also, I am not sure about this line:

```
var contractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, '0x3455D7167A2EE2d660EE85F8e90C6b3B1cCB7163');
```

that it must be :

```
var contractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, '<contract deployer address  = payer address>');
```

Or:

```
var contractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, '<contract address>');
```

**Which one is correct ?**

And also it's not because using [Tobalaba blockchain](https://github.com/energywebfoundation/energyweb-client) ? (that is base on Ethereum)

**Note:** Also I tested it by a version in which `function close` does **not** verify the **signature**, however the result is the same.

And alternatively, is there other ***test blockchain*** like `Tobalaba` blockchain based on `Ethereum` (and also ***free***) to test this `contract` ? since maybe the problem is related to this `Ethereum` based `blockchain`. I am not sure.

Comment: It should be `new web3.eth.Contract(abi, '<contract address>');`.

Comment: Ropsten, Rinkeby, and Kovan are the standard Ethereum test networks. You can also test locally with `ganache`.

Comment: @smarx  Thank you, Do you mean `testRPC = ganache` ? If so do you mean I need to deploy contract using `remix` ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, `ganache` is the new name for what used to be called `testrpc`. Whether you deploy with Remix or code (as you've done here) has nothing to do with whether you're using Ropsten, `ganache`, or anything else.