# How to give a non-zero balance to a contract at time of deployment using Remix?

Tags: remix, wallets, contract-deployment, accounts, balances

In case we want to deploy a contract by `web3.js` we can easily determine the balance of the contract at time of deployment as follows:

```
const thisContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi);
thisContract.deploy({  
        data: bytecode,
        arguments: [< parameters of the constructor>]
    }).send({
       from: "0x3455D7167A2EE2d660EE85F8e90C6b3B1cCB7163",
       gas: 5000000 ,
       gasPrice: '3000000000',
       value: 5000 // here we determine the balance of the contract 
    },
    function(error, transactionHash) {
        console.log(error);
        console.log(transactionHash);
        console.log('function exec');
    }).then(function(newContractInstance) {
    console.log('Contract Instance:' + newContractInstance.options.address);
});
```

In this example, the balance of the contract is `value: 5000`.

However, when we want to do this by `remix`, is there any option to determine the `value of the balance of the contract` at ***time of deployment*** ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the constructor payable and set a non-zero value for the ether before hitting deploy (see image)

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, in fact I asked this question, because I have a problem to make a settlement between `payer` and `recipient` using an `Ethereum` base blockchain (testnet) named `Tobalaba` ([link](https://github.com/energywebfoundation/energyweb-client)) I explained the problem here ([link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/53232/updated-what-is-missing-to-make-a-successful-payment-between-payer-and)) So, I decided to test this contract by `remix` to find what is the problem. I appreciate any idea to solve this problem. Thanks