# What happens if the "balance" of the address which sends "address.transfer(amount) is " zero "?

Tags: ether, accounts, addresses, balances, address.transfer

Consider the balance of the address that sends `address.transfer(amount);` to receive the `amount` is `zero`.

For example we have following `address` with balance of `zero`:

```
web3.eth.getBalance('0x123').then(console.log) // 0
```

And then this `address` wants to receive some `ether` as follows in `Solidity` code:

```
address public recipient;  // The account receiving the payments.

function receive(uint256 amount) public {
        require(msg.sender == recipient);

        recipient.transfer(amount);

    }
```

And at th time of deploying the contract, we initiate `recipient` to `0x123`:

```
constructor(address _recipient)
        public
        payable
    {
        recipient = _recipient;
    }
```

Also, we initiate the `balance of the contract` at the time of deployment.

Then this `address` tries to call `function receive` to receive `10 wei` as follows (consider the `contract address` is `0x456`) :

```
var contractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, '0x456' /*0x456 is contract address*/);

contractInstance.methods.close(10 /*0x123 wants to receive 10 wei*/).send({ from: '0x123' }, function(error, result) {

        console.log(error);

        console.log(result)

    });
```

when I do this, apparently nothing happens, because when I get the `recipient` balance, it is still `zero`.

**What is my mistake ?**

Comment: Is the transaction reverted? Is the recipient a smart contract? Does the contract at address `0x456` have enough balance? Are you calling `receive` from account `0x123`?

Comment: @Henk Thank you. Sometimes I receive this error: "`Error: Transaction ran out of gas. Please provide more gas:`". Please have a look at this question: HERE : [link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/53232/what-is-missing-to-make-a-successful-payment-between-payer-and-recipient?noredirect=1#comment63225_53232)   `contract address = 0x456`, `recipient address = 0x123`, when I send `10 wei`, balance of contract is `100 wei` and `function receive` is called by `0x123` Thanks